# C# opengl texture

Tags: c#, opengl, textures

I want to use textures in opengl on my C# application.
I'm using the Tao Framework and I used this code

http://www.gamedev.net/community/for...opic_id=405453 (post #2)

But I got this runtime error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'DevIL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Could someone help me?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Error message has full information you need. Find DevIL.dll in the internets (if you don't have it) and place anywhere on the path (in program directory on in [windows directory]\system32).

Comment: DevIL is an image loading library : http://openil.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I even placed it in sysyem32 but it dose not work

Comment: Btw, Is there any other way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with GLU.FreeGLUT.dll but when I installed Tao Framework solved my problem .
before that i copy dll to win32 and there was in dotnet Directory and add to references in project but I recieved this message : "An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' "

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the loading of the dll. You should make sure the dll is properly importer in your project through the references. Also make sure that you haven't moved or deleted the dll after you have added it to your project.

Comment: I added it to my references
And I haven't moved it!

Comment: Then, did you check if you have read access to the file, and everything is fine? What is sure is that Visual Studio doesn't have access to the file or fail to find it, so there must be an issue with it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I am.
And if VS can't access it, why when I'm typing it can detect module's name

Comment: Maybe it is about dll registration (or something like that) ?

Answer (score 0):

It suggests you are missing [DevIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevIL).  Try getting it and installing it before proceeding.